# How to stop all hints from progress davaserver for oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, progress-4gl, openedge

I am using progress 10.2 data server for oracle. I have already added -noindexhint parameter in data server to stop index hints. But still I am getting hints such as /*+ FIRST_ROWS  */, I want to remove it. Kindly let me know.

Comment: Don't you have to explicitly include [`QUERY-TUNING (HINT "FIRST_ROWS")](http://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmora/query-tuning.html) to see that hint?

Comment: I am not 100% certain you can stop all hints. Certain statements like CAN-FIND and FIND FIRST are still likely to send hints regardless of the settings. Post some examples and try and track down the source program to make sure they are not providing hints in the code.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this from the Oracle side (create a logon trigger that sets `alter session set "_optimizer_ignore_hints"=true;`, create profiles to ignore hints for specific statements, etc.).  But I wouldn't recommend that approach unless there's no good way to do it from the application side.

Comment: I can not stop it from oracle side as same DB is been used by multiple applications. They probably need those hints. Is there any way to stop it from progress data server side?

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yes we need to use query-tunning option. As per Oracle DBA, due these hints queries taking much time. They says let oracle handle everything.

Comment: If they say to let Oracle handle everything then don't use the query-tuning option. You don't need to use them if (a) the DBA says not to and (b) they make performance worse.

Comment: @alexpoole: Query tuning is used to check query conversion from ABL to SQL. It does not have any relation with hints.

Comment: `QUERY-TUNING (HINT ...)` does have a relation to hints. But why not include a sample ABL and the converted (hinted) SQL in the question so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @alexpoole: thanks for input. checked for sample code where query tuning not included, used noindexhint parameter for data server of oracle. Still hints are passed from Data server to oracle. Checked same using query-tuning(Debug SQL) mode. Is there any way to stop these?

Comment: @nileshpharate You can create the logon trigger to only run for specific sessions.  You can filter by username, host, etc.

Comment: I also want to know use of /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ hint in query. I mean is it really necessary to add this hint in query while conversion of ABL query to SQL query. Can we stop it using any start up parameter?